# Trigger click event on "a href" element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to click a href element on my html website. Problem is that click event is not triggered

CODE:

HTML CODE:

```
  <div class="button" id="info" ></div>
<ul id="game-options">

    <li><a href="#" id="SHOW_HELP" class="button help" title="Help">HELP</a></li>
</ul>
```

Function that clicks a href element:

```
 $('#info').bind('click', function(e) {
            alert ("button click triggered");
    // This is what I tried so fat

     //$('#SHOW_HELP').trigger('click');
     //$('#SHOW_HELP').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
     $('#SHOW_HELP').click();
});
```

Comment: The question is, what are you exepecting when the anchor is clicked, it doesn't really seem to do anything ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The click event is triggered, but you haven't bound a click handler so nothing will happen. If you want to simulate clicking the link you need to use the dom click method, ie. `$('#SHOW_HELP')[0].click();`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can update the button's click event to change the `window.location` in JavaScript.

**Try this:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#info').click(function(){
        window.location = $('#SHOW_HELP').attr('href');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#SHOW_HELP').bind('click', function(e) {
        alert ("button click triggered");
// This is what I tried so fat

 //$('#SHOW_HELP').trigger('click');
 //$('#SHOW_HELP').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));

});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8pJ66/)

Hope it helps you

Comment: **Don't use `bind` it is deprecated...!**

Answer (score 0):

It's actually working.

Here a JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/rZbk7/

```
$('#info').on('click', function(e) {
   alert("info triggered");
   $('#show-help').click();
});

$('#show-help').on('click', function(e) {
   alert("show-help triggered");
});
```

(not a big fun of snake case, I changed the name SHOW_HELP to show-help)

Click event is triggered. The problem is that you didn't define any action.